# Laravel Middleware non-object for Database Value

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I recently started working with `php Laravel` so I might be off base here, but I figured it won't hurt to ask.

I am trying to determine the preferred language of each user. Doing so on the `blades` gets the job done, but I read that it should be set outside the `blade` pages.

I made a new `Middleware` and I can set it up there, but I am not sure why it doesn't catch the actual `database` value.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
        if (Auth::User())
            App::setLocale(Auth::User()->lang);
        else
            App::setLocale('en');

    return $next($request);
}
```

This part `App::setLocale('en');` works fine and it sets up the locale to all pages. The condition above it `Auth::User()` is never true though so locale is never being set up based on the `lang` value. When I try to run it anyway, it gives an `ErrorException - Trying to get property of non-object` error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't test this right now but isnt the `Auth::user()` case sensitive? `Auth::User()` ---> `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 1):

BUDDY! 
try `$locale = App::getLocale();` instead of `Auth::User()->lang` 
you owe me a FIFA Game!